# PHP/AJAX/jQuery Select Box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my shipping section, I have a Country/State option. Whenever the user changes the country (select), I use ajax to check to see if there is a list of states for that country. If there is, a dropdown will appear with those states pouplated. If there is a not, an input box will be displayed so they can manually enter their state. I also have a "Saved Addresses" section on the side that will autopopulate the form using ajax if they have a saved address. I'm running into problems with the country/state values - the state is being set before the country value, so when the country value is set it triggers the states to refresh, erasing the value. Here's my code (I'm leaving out the PHP ajax requests since those are working - they just grab the data from the database and return a JSON array):

Note: This page can be visited at any time. If the user visits this page, fills it out, and visits it again later, the form should be populated with the appropriate information from the database (ie: the proper country/state should be displayed).

HTML (hide both input and select initially):

```
<label>State/Province</label>

<input  type="text" id="shipping_state_input" name="data[Order][shipping_state_input]" style="display: none;" <?php if(isset($this->request->data['Order']['shipping_state'])) { echo "value='" . $this->request->data['Order']['shipping_state'] . "'"; } ?>>
<select id="order_shipping_state" name="data[Order][shipping_state]" class="required span6" style="width: 180px; display: none;">
```

JS:

```
// Update the country
$('#order_shipping_country').change(function() {
    var country = $(this).val();

    // Get a list of states for that country
    $.getJSON("/states/ajax_getStatesByCountry/"+country, function(data) {
        // If a list is returned, populate the select box
        if(data) {
            $('#shipping_state_select').empty().show().addClass('state_active');
            $('#shipping_state_input').val('').hide().removeClass('state_active');

            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                $('<option/>').attr('value', key).html(val).appendTo('#shipping_state_select');
            });
        } else {
            // Otherwise, show the select box
            $('#shipping_state_select').empty().hide().removeClass('state_active');;
            $('#shipping_state_input').show().addClass('state_active');;
        }
    });
});

// If they click on a previous address
$('.previous_address').change(function() {
    var addr_id = $(this).val();

    if(addr_id != '') {
        // Get the address
        $.getJSON("/UserAddresses/ajax_get_address/" + addr_id,{ajax: 'true'}, function(j) {

            $.each(j, function(key, value){
                // Update state & country with the appropriate values
                // I've harded the array to return 'country' first...

                // .state_active is either attached to the select box or input box
                // the code below is hard coded for the US (I know the US is a select box)

                if(key == 'state') {
                    if($('#order_' + c + '_country').val() == 'US') {   
                        $('.state_active').find('option[value="UT"]').attr('selected', true);
                    } else {
                        $('.state_active').val(value);
                    }
                }

                if(key == 'country') {
                    $('#order_' + c + '_country').val(value).trigger('change'); 
                }
            })
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: I know that there is a question buried in there somewhere.

Comment: I didn't see it, @JayBlanchard.

What's the problem?

Comment: " I'm running into problems with the country/state values - the state is being set before the country value, so when the country value is set it triggers the states to refresh, erasing the value. "

Comment: So don't do it like you're doing it. `$.each(...` how about `if (key == 'state') { // save this for after the each completes so you know country was already done }` `...); // Now do state part`

Comment: this is a bit of a [fix my code question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions?cb=1#253788)

Comment: No, I don't want my code fixed. I'm just not understanding the best way to do this, so I'm asking for help. I've been troubleshooting this for a few hours and am stuck.

Comment: Also, I don't know if I'm going about this the correct way. This way is just what made the most sense to me, but maybe there's an easier/cleaner/better way?